# Convert Integer back to SecByteBlock?

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++, diffie-hellman

I'm using the Crypto++ library:

```
DH dh;
AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
SecByteBlock priv(dh.PrivateKeyLength());
SecByteBlock pub(dh.PublicKeyLength());
```

This generates the private and public key using diffie-hellman:

```
dh.GenerateKeyPair(rnd, priv, pub);
```

Here I convert unreadable private and public keys to `Integer` (num e.g. 123)

```
// SecByteBlock -convert-> Integer
Integer a, b;
a.Decode(priv.BytePtr(), priv.SizeInBytes());
b.Decode(pub.BytePtr(), pub.SizeInBytes());
```

What is the code for me to convert back from `Integer` to `SecByteBlock`?

```
Integer -convert-> SecByteBlock
```

Comment: Isn't the idea of a `SecByteBlock` lost if you construct it from a less safe type? If I understand the name (the API is severely lacking information) then the idea is that this block is in secured memory. When you are generating it from insecure memory, a large part of the security is lost.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - `Integer` stores the bignum bytes in a `SecBlock`-based type too (`SecByteBlock` is a typedef for `SecBlock<byte>`). Based on a cursory reading of the source, the only security feature is zero-ing of the memory on deallocation; I see no evidence of it preventing swapping to disk. I suppose that in the face of, for example, Heartbleed-style attacks zero-ing could provide some benefit, but the real mitigation against leaking key material in the context of the OP's question would obviously be to use an HSM not a software crypto library anyway.

Comment: @softwariness That's great info, thanks for that. Even I don't have a HSM lying around at home though (wouldn't fit in my laptop anyway :) )

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's a good point ;-)

Comment: @Maarten - Good observation; you're not the first. Crypto++ has a lot of self documenting code and a wiki to try and fill in the gaps. You can find the wiki at [Crypto++ Wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the bytes out of an `Integer`, you use the `MinEncodedSize` and  `Encode` methods ([see the Crypto++ documentation](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html#a3b269bbf8a91faf217c0dd76222182bb)). Note that the encoding is big-endian.

Here's an example method  to wrap that up (which assumes the `Integer` is unsigned, as would apply in this case):

```
void UnsignedIntegerToByteBlock(const Integer& x, SecByteBlock& bytes)
{
    size_t encodedSize = x.MinEncodedSize(Integer::UNSIGNED);
    bytes.resize(encodedSize);
    x.Encode(bytes.BytePtr(), encodedSize, Integer::UNSIGNED);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Integer a;
// ...
SecByteBlock bbA;
UnsignedIntegerToByteBlock(a, bbA);
```

Comment: *"Note that the encoding is big-endian"* - we started adding *some* little endian support to the Integer class; see [Integer Patch](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Integer_Patch). But the support was *not* extended to the various *Encode* and *Decode* methods.